# Ajax always executes error function on success with Asp.Net HttpResponseMessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

When I send my Ajax request I can see that the returned status code is 200 which means everything worked fine. However, it always executes the error function instead of the success function.

**Web Api**

```
public HttpResponseMessage ChangeModus(Artikel Artikel)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/Api/Artikel/ChangeModus",
    data: JSON.stringify(Artikel),
    success: OnSaveSuccess,
    error: OnSaveError
});

function OnSaveSuccess(response) {
    alert("Success")
}

function OnSaveError(response) {
    alert("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten");
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or why does it always execute the Error function?

Comment: What is the error you're getting back in your error function? It'd help to know which error it is.

Comment: It doesn't return any error. The response inside the error function shows status code 200. I will append a screenshot @Jacob

Comment: Also, does your response include a body? I'm not sure if that's the cause of the issue or not, but you should use a `204` response (`HttpStatusCode.NoContent`) for success with no response body.

Comment: Thats it!! Thanks so much. If I do this Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success"); it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is occurring because although you have a 200 (OK) response, the response does not include a response body. You should either send content with the response, or use `HttpStatusCode.NoContent` (204) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jakob said, the problem occurs because there has to be a response body otherwise javascript will execute the error function.

Choose one of the following options:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ChangeModus(Artikel Artikel)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
}
```

Or:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ChangeModus(Artikel Artikel)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```